# Too much sugar - HELP

Tags: baking

I'm making a cinnamon raisin bread.  The recipe calls for 5 3/4 cups of flour and 4 tsp of sugar in the first part.  Later on it calls for 3/4 cups of sugar mixed with cinnamon.  I was working the recipe from my computer screen and somehow missed the first sugar in the ingredients and added the 3/4 cups to the dough. I didn't realize the mistake until it was already proofing.  I did add some extra water to the knead, but not enough.  The dough is barely rising after 2 hours.  What can I expect the results to be?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It will not go well, as I think you already have guessed.

The reason for this is that concentrations of sugar over about 4-5% are inhibitory to yeast growth in bread making. You need the yeast growth to make the bubbles of carbon dioxide that cause the bread to rise.

The only reference I could find for this is from [Food and Feed Technology](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=f--1V1ftgtsC&lpg=RA1-PA729&ots=p_PbgM8Ayq&dq=inhibitory%20concentration%20of%20sugar%20in%20bread&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=inhibitory%20concentration%20of%20sugar%20in%20bread&f=false) p. 729.

> ...sugar concentrations ~4% produce apparent inhibition...

The book then goes on to say:

> Consequently sweet yeast raised breads (15-20% sugar) contain very high yeast concentrations

Your concentration of sugar is about 13% (0.75/5.75), well above where it needs to be for the bread to rise with regular amounts of yeast.

I suspect that you won't be able to resurrect it by adding extra yeast at this point, it would be over-kneaded and probably won't rise all that well, or will rise and then collapse during baking. Your only sure way is to start again and follow the recipe.

Comment: Thank you.  As you can guess, I'm still in the process of making this loaf.  I'm this far along so I guess I'll finish it.  But then, as you suggest, I'll start over and do it right.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just took the loaves out of he oven.  The dough finally rose, but I don't think it doubled.  And it barely rose the second time.  It's pretty dense, but I've never made this before, so I have nothing to compare it to. It's also not as sweet as I thought it would be. It's sweet, but not sickeningly sweet. I will make it again correctly.  But at least it didn't end up in the garbage can.